# How do you scan a usb connection for files?

Tags: file, filesystems, lego-mindstorms

i want a way to scan a usb for files, i dont care if this is an application or a piece of code

Note:
this is related to Lego Mindstorms Robot Inventor HUB,
i want to scan the hub and get the files from it,
if there is a better way, just say it

- henos

Answer (score 1):

You’ll likely use PyUSB (https://github.com/pyusb/pyusb) for general USB connections. Be forewarned that you may not be able to access the Hub directly through the port of LEGO set things up to require all communication to go through their app, but I have not attempted to do that.

Comment: By Lego setting it up to use the app only, I looked through the connection logs, and saw
`scanning USB` and `using localhost:XXXX`

Comment: Is that how it did that or is it something different